# I want the full verision of my website to appear in mobile browsers

Tags: java, html, css

How can I make it do this without scaling down? I just want people to have to zoom in. is it possible? my website is not mobile friendly atm :(

Comment: can you provide some sample code that replicates the problem you're having?  a site should default to not "scaling down" unless you're using some sort of responsive ui / css framework

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't include the `viewport` meta tag, you'll get the experience you're looking for.

Comment: I dont have a viewport yet my site divs leave sections and such, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

the website might look different because the way you sized your element.
(are you using px or %)

you have to remember that most smart phone still have 800 pixel width, even though it is smaller.